# Finding T-SQL code with literal strings for localization project

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, localization

Does anyone have experience with tools/techniques that would help identify T-SQL code with literal strings (that may require language translation for a localization project)?  Would love to leverage another's experience that may save me time developing my own tool or - god forbid - doing it manually.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083985/search-all-stored-procs-for-a-literal-or-string

Comment: @OMGPonies Not looking for a particular string, but sps/functions with any literal strings.

Comment: This was asked within the last two days, and I can't find it -- likely was moved to dba. overflow...

Comment: "Related" -- reading comprehension...

Comment: Think I found what you were looking for... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5084989/how-best-to-find-hard-coded-english-language-strings-in-sql-server-stored-procedu

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea, but you could do something like this:

```
SELECT
    OBJECT_NAME(id),
    [text]
FROM
    syscomments
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM syscomments 
    WHERE [text] LIKE '%''%''%' 
    AND OBJECTPROPERTY(id, 'IsProcedure') = 1 
    GROUP BY id
)
```

That will show every procedure with a constant string literal in it.

Of course, if you use too many dynamic SQL execution statements, you'll get a lot of false positives...

Hope it helps.

Comment: Helps eliminate some.  Thanks.